# Jest React Example fails

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to run a test using the sample code given by react.

I have imported react to my test file using: import React from 'react';
This is my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "newjest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "testing the test",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "15.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "^5.3.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^5.3.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^5.3.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^5.3.0",
    "enzyme": "*",
    "jest": "*",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.4.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "author": "suparna",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

It fails with the error, Test suite failed to run, Cannot find module 'react'

```
> newjest@1.0.0 test /Users/suparnasoman/Desktop/newjest
> jest

 FAIL  __tests__/CheckboxWithLabel-test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

        Cannot find module 'react' from 'CheckboxWithLabel-test.js'

          at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:191:17)
          at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/CheckboxWithLabel-test.js:3:14)
```

And here is the code for my CheckboxWithLabel-test.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import CheckboxWithLabel from '../CheckboxWithLabel';

test('CheckboxWithLabel changes the text after click', () => {
  // Render a checkbox with label in the document
  const checkbox = shallow(
    <CheckboxWithLabel labelOn="On" labelOff="Off" />
  );

  expect(checkbox.text()).toEqual('Off');

  checkbox.find('input').simulate('change');

  expect(checkbox.text()).toEqual('On');
});
```

Comment: Please provide a complete code example that causes this error. It should be as small as possible. For tips on creating an example, read [mcve].

Comment: did you import react into your test file?

Comment: yes @azium I have. import React from 'react';

Comment: Can you provide the code for CheckboxWithLabel-test.js?

Comment: code updated  the description @BenHare

Comment: Have you run `npm install`?